# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key, works fine in spyder and jupyter notebook but not in pycharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have two text columns, I am trying to check if words from one column is in another column.
Tried below code,

```
df[[x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(df['country'], df['movie_title'])]][['movie_title', 'country']]
```

and tried

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.country in x.movie_title, axis=1)][['movie_title', 'country']]
```

it works fine in jupyter notebook and spyder, but the same code throws error in pycharm. Tried by filling `'na'` with values still same error.
I am trying to build web application in pycharm, hence need the code to be running without error.

Tried most of the links posted but couldn't find solution for this. Any leads appreciated.

Comment: *Throws error.* It would be helpful to know *what* error.

Comment: This is the error message: "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"